# Dynamic PHP PDO MYSQL query doesn't Update [No error returned]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

Ok, i try to make an update query with PDO MYSQL so to learn how make it work and then make a function to make it more efficiently

The problem is doesn't work, i do all the debugg the Log files allow me, and the personal returns too, i alsy fix wherever the navigator tell & even with Firebug

Any ideas what can be?

Any suggestion, question, comment or any kind of answer than help to improve, clarify or answer the question would be much aprreciated

Thanks in advance

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
session_start();


 $idf = $_POST['Id_Msg'];
 $ids = (int) $idf;

 var_dump($ids);
  echo '<br /><br />';
 var_dump($_FILES);

 echo '<br /><br />';
 var_dump($_POST);
 echo '<br /><br />';

  $wlq = -1;

 if($_POST['Title']) {
     $wlq++;
 }
 if($_POST['Prelude']) {
     $wlq++;
 }

 if($_POST['Text']) {
     $wlq++;
 }

 if($_POST['NOMBR1']) {
     $wlq++;
 }

 if($_POST['NOMBR2']) {
     $wlq++;
 }

 if($_POST['NOMBR3']) {
     $wlq++;
 }

 if($_POST['NOMBR4']) {
     $wlq++;
 }

 if($_POST['REGIN']) {
     $wlq++;
 }

 if($_POST['CTGRY']) {
     $wlq++;
 }

 if(!empty($_FILES['RutIm']['name'])) {
     $wlq++;
     echo 'me esta detectando visteh!';
 }

 echo "Asignado es: ".$wlq.'<br /><br />';

 $qls = "UPDATE `cmtmplo` SET";

 if($_POST['Title']) {
     if($wlq > 0){
    $qls .=" `Title` = :Title , ";
    $wlq--;
     } else {
    $qls .=" `Title` = :Title";
    }
 }

 if($_POST['Prelude']) {
     if($wlq > 0){
    $qls .=" `Prelude` = :Prelude , ";
    $wlq--;
     } else {
    $qls .=" `Prelude` = :Prelude";
    }
 }

 if($_POST['Text']) {
     if($wlq > 0){
    $qls .=" `Text` = :Text , ";
    $wlq--;
     } else {
    $qls .=" `Text` = :Text";
    }
 }

 if($_POST['NOMBR1']) {
     if($wlq > 0){
    $qls .=" `NOMBR1` = :NOMBR1 , ";
    $wlq--;
     } else {
    $qls .=" `NOMBR1` = :NOMBR1";
    }
 }

 if($_POST['NOMBR2']) {
     if($wlq > 0){
    $qls .=" `NOMBR2` = :NOMBR2 , ";
    $wlq--;
     } else {
    $qls .=" `NOMBR2` = :NOMBR2";
    }
 }

 if($_POST['NOMBR3']) {
     if($wlq > 0){
    $qls .=" `NOMBR3` = :NOMBR3 , ";
    $wlq--;
     } else {
    $qls .=" `NOMBR3` = :NOMBR3";
    }
 }

 if($_POST['NOMBR4']) {
     if($wlq > 0){
    $qls .=" `NOMBR4` = :NOMBR4 , ";
    $wlq--;
     } else {
    $qls .=" `NOMBR4` = :NOMBR4";
    }
 }

 if($_POST['REGIN']) {
     if($wlq > 0){
    $qls .=" `REGIN` = :REGIN , ";
    $wlq--;
     } else {
    $qls .=" `REGIN` = :REGIN";
    }
 }

 if($_POST['CTGRY']) {
     if($wlq > 0){
    $qls .=" `CTGRY` = :CTGRY , ";
    $wlq--;
     } else {
    $qls .=" `CTGRY` = :CTGRY";
    }
 }

 if(!empty($_FILES['RutIm']['name'])) {
     if($wlq > 0){
    $qls .=" `RutIm` = :RutIm , ";
    $wlq--;
     } else {

    }
 }

 $qls .= " WHERE 'Id_Msg' = :ids";
 echo $qls;
 $stmt = $con->prepare($qls);
 $stmt->bindValue(':ids', $ids);

 if(isset($_POST['Title']) && !empty($_POST['Title'])) {
    $stmt->bindValue('Title', $_POST['Title']);
 } 

 if(isset($_POST['Prelude']) && !empty($_POST['Prelude'])) {
    $stmt->bindValue('Prelude', $_POST['Prelude']);
 } 

 if(isset($_POST['Text']) && !empty($_POST['Text'])) {
    $stmt->bindValue('Text', $_POST['Text']);
 } 

 if(isset($_POST['NOMBR1']) && !empty($_POST['NOMBR1'])) {
    $stmt->bindValue('NOMBR1', $_POST['NOMBR1']);
 } 

 if(isset($_POST['NOMBR2']) && !empty($_POST['NOMBR2'])) {
    $stmt->bindValue('NOMBR2', $_POST['NOMBR2']);
 } 

 if(isset($_POST['NOMBR3']) && !empty($_POST['NOMBR3'])) {
    $stmt->bindValue('NOMBR3', $_POST['NOMBR3']);
 } 

 if(isset($_POST['NOMBR4']) && !empty($_POST['NOMBR4'])) {
    $stmt->bindValue('NOMBR4', $_POST['NOMBR4']);
 }

 if(isset($_POST['REGIN']) && !empty($_POST['REGIN'])) {
    $stmt->bindValue('REGIN', $_POST['REGIN']);
 }

 if(isset($_POST['CTGRY']) && !empty($_POST['CTGRY'])) {
    $stmt->bindValue('CTGRY', $_POST['CTGRY']);
 }

 if(!empty($_FILES['RutIm']['name'])) {
    $carpeta = "images/";
    opendir($carpeta);
    $destiny = $carpeta.$_FILES['RutIm']['name'].".jpg";
    copy($_FILES['RutIm']['tmp_name'],$destiny);
    $skr=$_FILES['RutIm']['name'];
    $stmt->bindValue('RutIm', $skr);    
 }
$stmt->execute(); 
?>
```

**echo $qls output**

`UPDATE cmtmplo SET Title = :Title , REGIN = :REGIN , CTGRY = :CTGRY WHERE 'Id_Msg' = :ids`

Comment: so what is your `echo $qls;` outputs?

Comment: it depends of what parts i add text and what others not, but this is what returns with the current tests UPDATE `cmtmplo` SET `Title` = :Title , `REGIN` = :REGIN , `CTGRY` = :CTGRY WHERE 'Id_Msg' = :ids

Comment: so show me the output with `$qls` please?

Comment: how can i get the output in this case of PDO Mysql?

Comment: `echo $qls;`  before your `$con->prepare`!

Comment: it is just before $con->prepare already, the comment who said "it depends..:" have that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need change all labels like `'Title'` to `':Title'`:

```
 if(isset($_POST['Title']) && !empty($_POST['Title'])) {
    $stmt->bindValue(':Title', $_POST['Title']);
 } 

....
```

and so on... all parameters you bind must start with `:`

so now we can see that you should change

```
$qls .= " WHERE 'Id_Msg' = :ids";
```

to

```
$qls .= " WHERE `Id_Msg` = :ids";
```

apostrophs to ticks

Comment: Try, and you are all right, but it still doesn't update

Comment: the colon is not required

Comment: @user57129 so now we can see that you shod change `$qls .= " WHERE 'Id_Msg' = :ids";` to  `$qls .= " WHERE \`Id_Msg\` = :ids";` spostrophs to ticks

Comment: Boy, what an eye you have, effectively, it was the `$qls .= " WHERE 'Id_Msg' = :ids";` when i change it to `$qls .= " WHERE `Id_Msg` = :ids";` it works like a charm, thanks you

Answer (score 2):

PHP PDO provides a good way of finding out what might be wrong with the query.
[`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) only returns true or false by default. It won't return any specific detail.

For detailed error information, you can use:

```
var_dump($con->errorInfo());
```

For more details, refer to the documentation page: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: Also `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` will enable exception-based error handling if that sort of thing turns your crank.

Comment: could you instance it in this code case?, i'm not so used to use this error handlers, thanks

Comment: @user57129 in your code specifically, you can do something like: `if($stmt->execute()){ echo 'Successfully updated' } else { print_r($con->errorInfo()) }`

Comment: Thanks, i'll add it but is returning 'Successfully updated' However the database remains unchanged